# WPF grid questions - setting one up programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display a grid of images.  Initially the grid will be empty and then it will gradually fill in as the images arrive from an external device, possibly in random order, i.e., I may get the image for location (1,3) and then (5,5) etc.

The dimensions will be known at runtime, but before I display the grid, so I have to set them programmatically, not in the XAML.

**1.** The examples I've found on the web show how to define Grid rows and columns in XAML, but how do I do it programmatically in C#, i.e., if a 5x4 Grid is specified I want to the user to see an empty 5x4 Grid initially.

**2.**  How do I programmatically access/alter elements at individual grid locations?  When the grid is empty I'll want to initially show something in each empty spot (like an "X" or a colored rectangle) and then replace it with the actual image when it arrives.   In C# how do I access Grid location (x,y) to add or change what's in it?

**3**  Do Grids have any intrinsic scrolling ability or do I have to wrap them in a separate scrolling control, i.e.,

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
    </Grid> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

... and if I do this can I set it for scrollbars to only appear if they are needed based on the size?

Comment: To not make the scrollbar always show up, remove the scrollviewer. It will work as intended once you remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's easy, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.aspx)

   ```
       // Create the Grid
       Grid myGrid = new Grid();
       myGrid.Width = 250;
       myGrid.Height = 100;
       myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
       myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

       // Define the Columns
       ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
       ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
       ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
       myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
       myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
       myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

       // Define the Rows
       RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
       RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
       RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
       RowDefinition rowDef4 = new RowDefinition();
       myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
       myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
       myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
       myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef4);

       // Add the first text cell to the Grid
       TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
       txt1.Text = "2005 Products Shipped";
       txt1.FontSize = 20; 
       txt1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
       Grid.SetColumnSpan(txt1, 3);
       Grid.SetRow(txt1, 0);

       ...
       myGrid.Children.Add(txt1);
       mainWindow.Content = myGrid
   ```
2. [Set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3745594/1997232) grid position, [get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511802/1997232) it (getting is more complicated)
3. I'd probably use `ListBox` in your case, with `WrapPanel`. You will get selection (multiple selection?) and scrolling as a bonus. Search for "wpf listbox wrappanel", to example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818876/1997232) is something.

Comment: Your Grid suggestions worked great (got the layout and grid lines, etc) **except** for the text.    No text appears and also I don't understand how the text is inserted since you don't reference "myGrid" just the general Grid class, so how does it know you mean that particular grid?   I tried replacing "Grid" with "myGrid" and got "cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: `Grid.SetRow()` is [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). And yes, you are right, my example is not complete, it miss `myGrid.Children.Add(txt1);`, but you can find a complete in the msdn link for first question answer (and some more info).